# Quorum 7nodes example unable to finish simplestorage migration using privateFor

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, quorum

I'm following this example: [truffle quorum example](https://truffleframework.com/tutorials/building-dapps-for-quorum-private-enterprise-blockchains) I created a cluster using docker-compose and all the nodes are up and running but when I run the `truffle migrate` command the migration doesn't end and finishes like this:

```
λ truffle.cmd migrate --reset

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.


Starting migrations...
======================
> Network name:    'development'
> Network id:      10
> Block gas limit: 1702452429


1_initial_migration.js
======================

   Replacing 'Migrations'
   ----------------------
   > transaction hash:    0xbb9fc26e04cd017c3e69a37fd2d0062553c749fd752cbc2f67a1727af519c7e1
   > Blocks: 0            Seconds: 0
   > contract address:    0xd0a5685a4ba479D0FF4E86Ca8300738573816c63
   > account:             0xed9d02e382b34818e88B88a309c7fe71E65f419d
   > balance:             1000000000
   > gas used:            284908
   > gas price:           0 gwei
   > value sent:          0 ETH
   > total cost:          0 ETH


   > Saving migration to chain.
   > Saving artifacts
   -------------------------------------
   > Total cost:                   0 ETH


2_deploy_simplestorage.js
=========================

   Deploying 'SimpleStorage'
   -------------------------
```

It doesn't give any error but it doesn't finish migrating.

If I remove `{privateFor: ["oNspPPgszVUFw0qmGFfWwh1uxVUXgvBxleXORHj07g8="]}` from the migrations\2_deploy_simplestorage.js then the migration is able to finish.

I checked the public key of the seventh node and its correct.

How can I run this example?

I'm using Truffle v5.0.7 (core: 5.0.7), Solidity v0.5.0 (solc-js) and Node v10.15.2

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Truffle version prior to 5.0.14 have some Quorum related bugs. Please upgrade to 5.0.14+ and try again.